# JavaScript select tags remove selected option

Tags: html, node.js

I have a local server with NodeJs and on one page I have three select tags. I would like when one option in the first select tag is selected to completely remove it from the list of the other select tag. Unfortunately nothing seems to be happening. The file remove.js is in public/js (so don't think that's the problem)

html:

```
<script> src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/remove.js"></script>

<select name="rank1" size="1" id="select1" >
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Rank</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
 </select>

<select name="rank2" size="1" id="select2" >
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Rank</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
 </select>

<select name="rank3" size="1" id="select3" >
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Rank</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
 </select>
```

JavaScript remove.js:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("select").change(function(){
       var selectedValue1 = $(this).val();
       var selectedValue2 = $("select").not($(this)).val();
       $(this).find("option[value!="+selectedValue2+"]").show();
       $("select").not($(this)).find("option[value!="+selectedValue1+"]").show();
       $("select").not($(this)).find("option[value="+selectedValue1+"]").hide();
    });
  });
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You failed to include JQuery.

Change this :

```
<script>src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
```

To :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change javascript write this

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        var selected = 0
        var prevSelected = 0;
       $("select").change(function () {
            prevSelected = selected;
            selected = $(this).val();
            $("select").not("#"+this.id).each(function(){
                $("#"+this.id).find("[value=" + selected + "]").hide();
                $("#"+this.id).find("[value=" + prevSelected + "]").show();
            })
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work your original code wasn't working as expected.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var select1,select2,select3;

      $("#select1").change(function(){
        if(select1 > 0){
  $("#select2").find("option[value="+select1+"]").removeAttr('disabled');
  $("#select3").find("option[value="+select1+"]").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
        select1 = $(this).val();
  $("#select2").find("option[value="+select1+"]").attr("disabled","disabled");
  $("#select3").find("option[value="+select1+"]").attr("disabled","disabled");
    });

    $("#select2").change(function(){
    if(select2 > 0){
  $("#select1").find("option[value="+select2+"]").removeAttr('disabled');
  $("#select3").find("option[value="+select2+"]").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
        select2 = $(this).val();
  $("#select1").find("option[value="+select2+"]").attr("disabled","disabled");
  $("#select3").find("option[value="+select2+"]").attr("disabled","disabled");

    });

    $("#select3").change(function(){
     if(select3 > 0){
  $("#select1").find("option[value="+select3+"]").removeAttr('disabled');
  $("#select2").find("option[value="+select3+"]").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
        select3 = $(this).val();
  $("#select1").find("option[value="+select3+"]").attr("disabled","disabled");
  $("#select2").find("option[value="+select3+"]").attr("disabled","disabled");

  });


});
```

Comment: You should probably verify your solution. If this does not work then you've just mislead the OP..... Good luck mate.

Comment: @xhemil avdullahu This works but it disables them. I would like to remove them completely from the list. Changing disabled to hidden doesn't work...

Comment: Have you tried  ?$("#select1").find("option[value=4]").remove();